# Semicircle with proportion on picture.

Tags: geometry, circles

We folded such a sheet along the segment $ED$ so that the side of the circle touches the diameter at point $B$. (picture)

We only know that $AB$ = $7$ and $BC$ = $1$.

Need to find $ED$

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPbIY.png)

I think the answer is $\sqrt{40}$, but I haven't solved it..

P.S.
This is a school task and I don't understand why it is so difficult

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think the answer is $\sqrt{40}$?  What reasoning did you use, because it's remarkably close to the actual answer, yet it's not correct.

1. What is the radius of the circle whose diameter is $AC$?
2. Where is the center of this circle (the midpoint of $AC$)?  Call this point $O$.
3. What is the radius of the circle that contains the arc $EBD$?
4. Where is the center $P$ of the circle referenced in item #3 above?
5. How far apart are the centers of these two circles; that is to say, what is the length of $OP$?
6. What kind of figure is $OEPD$?